How to tackle the Laplace Transform of the $n$th derivative if we don't know $f^{(k)}(0)$ from boundary conditions?
The Laplace Transform for $n$th order derivatives is
$$\mathcal L\{y^{(n)}(t)\}=s^nF(s)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s^ky^{(n-1-k)}(0),$$
wherein there appear $\{y(0),y'(0), y''(0), ..., y^{(n-1)}(0)\}$.
My question is basically how can we cope with boundary conditions that don't include some or any of these terms? Maybe we could redefine the independent variable in some way? Or maybe we can't do anything about it?

Depends, usually you use the Laplace Transform to solve an intial value problem, if however some $y^{(k)}(0)$ is not given, but instead $y^{(k)}(a)=b$ for some other point $a\neq 0.$ Just let $y^{(k)}(0)$ be a parameter in the solution after transforming back. Then you fix this parameter by requiring that the boundary condition $y^{(k)}(a)=b.$

...otherwise said, to each unknown $f^{(k)}(0)$ is attached an arbitrary constant of integration.

We actually did a problem today that involved redefining the unknown constant; now it all makes sense, thank you.
